# This site can’t be reached aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy  node.js on AWS ec2
I followed [this tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/977/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-on-aws-ec2-server)  and that my code

```
const express = require('express') ;
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;

app.get('/', (req , res) =>{
  res.send('Connected');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);

});
```

and when I start it gives me the

> Example app listening at http://localhost:3000

but when I try to reach it from the browser I can't reach it
any idea what can I do or where to look ??

Comment: Did you follow the security group step of the tutorial? Do you know what security groups are?

Comment: isn't your app should be listening on all interfaces like `app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`  or be very specific `your.ec2.ip.address:3000` instead of `localhost` to allow you to reach from the internet? + you security groups should be allowing the incoming traffic on port `3000`

Comment: thank you it was a inbound rule problem , i didnt put the source  for the port range right .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure inbound and outbound rules in the instance's security group.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have already followed the guide you mentioned and added the necessary security group rules to allow the incoming traffic on port `3000`.

Your app should be listening on all the interfaces or on the IP address of your ec2 instance instead of `localhost`. `localhost` resolves to 127.0.0.1 which is a loopback interface that is not accessible over the internet.

[documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen)

> [app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])]

```js
const express = require('express') ;
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;

app.get('/', (req , res) =>{
  res.send('Connected');
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0',() => {
 console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);

});
```